# Factorize $ (kx-y+z)(x+ky-z)(x-y-kz)-(kx+y-z)(x-ky-z)(x-y+kz) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I tried opening the brackets but it keeps getting complex and complex. Does anyone have any easier way of doing it. Please tell how did you observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ f(x,y,z,k)=(kx-y+z)(x+ky-z)(x-y-kz)-(kx+y-z)(x-ky-z)(x-y+kz) \tag 1$$
Name the six terms respectively as :
$$f(x,y,z,k)=A*B*C-a*b*c$$
If $k=1$ we have $A=c$ , $B=b$ and $C=b$ thus $ABC=abc$ and $f(x,y,z,1)=0$. As a consequence $(k-1)$ is a factor of $f(x,y,z,k)$.

Do the same with $k=-1$ which leads to $f(x,y,z,-1)=0$ then a second factor $(k+1)$.

Proceeding on the same manner successively with $x=y$ , $y=z$ , and $z=x$ gives three other factors : $(x-y)$ , $(y-z)$ and $(z-x)$.

Finally
$$f(x,y,z,k)=-2(k-1)(k+1)(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\tag 2$$

The coefficient $-2$ is obtained in giving an arbitrary value to each $x,y,z,k$ , of course so that $f\neq 0$ , and comparing the values of Eq.$(1)$ and Eq.$(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Let $$P(x,y,z,k)=(kx-y+z)(x+ky-z)(x-y-kz)-(kx+y-z)(x-ky-z)(x-y+kz).$$
Prove that $$P(x,x,z,k)=P(x,y,x,k)=P(x,y,y,k)=P(x,y,z,\pm 1)=0.$$

Comment: This is a nice hint. Do you have any advice on how one would recognize that this is the right way to approach the problem? Are there more computational ways to do it?

Comment: Pls tell me why -2 come in J jacquelin answer ...I did not see comments box in his answer...but I have this doubt pls solve it..just tell me why -2 comes in last i did not understand his reasoning

Comment: Pls tell me fast ....